# How to crossfade 3 videos using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am currently using below command that is working fine for 2 videos but how to crossfade for 3 videos:

```
ffmpeg -report -i "video2.mp4" -i "video3.mp4" -an \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=start=0:end=9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[firstclip]; \
[1:v]trim=start=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[secondclip]; \
[0:v]trim=start=9:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeoutsrc]; \
[1:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeinsrc]; \
[fadeinsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadein]; \
[fadeoutsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadeout]; \
[fadein]fifo[fadeinfifo]; \
[fadeout]fifo[fadeoutfifo]; \
[fadeoutfifo][fadeinfifo]overlay[crossfade]; \
[firstclip][crossfade][secondclip]concat=n=3" \ outputname.mp4
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using that command twice (once with you first 2 videos and a second time with the resulting output and your 3rd video)?

Comment: @NonoxX thanks! but i want to run in one command only

Comment: Maybe you can pipe the result of one call to the other. This would kind of be “one command”. Is there a specific reason you want to do it on a single command?